# Backslashes not processed as command line arguments correctly

Tags: macos, perl

I have a script `displaytext.pl` which contains the following

```
print join(" ",@ARGV),"\n";
```

When I run it from my mac terminal using

```
perl displaytext.pl A\B
```

I get the output:

```
AB
```

However, when I run it as

```
perl displaytext.pl 'A\B'
```

The input is correctly interpreted as

```
A\B
```

What is the difference between passing string with quotes and string without quotes. Does it mean that if we have any escape characters, do we need to pass this as string?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Perl.  The backslash character `\\` is special to the shell and any time you are typing it in the Terminal it will be interpreted by the shell.  If you want to pass it to a command literally, you have to escape it or quote it.

Comment: @MarkReed: Please post your comment as an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Perl.

The backslash character `\` is special to the shell, which interprets everything you type in Terminal.

```
$ echo A\B
AB
```

In order to pass it literally to any command, even shell builtins like `echo`, you have to escape or quote it:

```
$ echo A\\B
A\B
$ echo 'A\B'
A\B
```

Comment: Yes, as would both `echo "A\B"` and `echo "A\\B"`.  Since the question already had `'A\B'`, I thought I would provide an alternative; I didn't intend to exhaust the possibilities.

Comment: Oops, I was distracted. Thought the `'A\B'` was in Perl code.